# Using asiatic jasmine for ground cover/weed control in shrub bed

Tags: weed-control, ground-cover, hedge

If I plant asiatic jasmine under mature hedges, will it choke or kill them?

This is in central Florida, hedges are (I believe) ligustrum and loropetalum.

Answer (score 2):

When you say asiatic jasmine, I'm assuming you mean Trachelospermum asiaticum, an evergreen twining climber with fragrant flowers. It won't exactly choke nor kill your plants as such, but it could smother them completely unless you keep it in check, and only let it cover the ground - usually a bit slow to grow initially, once settled in, it will attempt to scramble up over your hedges, so make sure you check it regularly and prevent it from doing that. It'll take up quite a bit of room, its eventual height and spread is 8m, so  on the ground, that's an 8m squared area...

Comment: Thanks, I googled Trachelospermum asiaticum, and this is what I'm thinking of although I don't recall seeing white flowers, unless maybe they are very small.  It will be a tradeoff I guess...trimming the jasmine back but not having to mulch and weed.

Comment: Flowers on that particular Trachelospermum are more of a buff colour - there's another one, Trachelospermum jasminoides, with white flowers. Neither is actually a Jasmine though....